# get number of functions within a class in python?

Tags: python, function

I have a problem and I hope you can provide me with an answer to it.

I'm trying to create a function that return the number of functions within a class that is stored in a python file ..  is there a good way to do so??

Comment: How do you define `functions`?

Comment: How do you define "stored in a python file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module:

```
class Test(object):
    def a(self):
        pass
    def b(self):
        pass


>>>>inspect.getmembers(Test, inspect.ismethod)
[('a', <unbound method Test.a>), ('b', <unbound method Test.b>)]
>>>>len(_)
2
```

---

Something like this should work for your second question:

```
import foo
import inspect

for a,b in inspect.getmembers(foo, inspect.isclass):
    print a 
    print len(inspect.getmembers(b, inspect.ismethod))
```

Comment: This should be the preferred method

Answer (score 3):

What I have tried:

```
>>> import types

>>> class Test(object):
    def a(self):
        pass
    def b(self):
        pass

>>> len([i for i in Test.__dict__.itervalues() if isinstance(i, types.FunctionType)])
2
```

Comment: thanks a lot its very helpful ,, but I still have a problem that the class names are in other files and I don't know there names here is my code
    import types
    import foo
    import inspect

    count=0
    for a,b in inspect.getmembers(foo):
        if inspect.isclass(b):
        print a        
        print len([i for i in a.__dict__.itervalues() if isinstance(i, types.FunctionType)])
but it give me error for putting a.__dicit__ , I need to specify the class name so is there any way I can do that?

Comment: If you use `inspect`, see @KayZhu 's answer.

Comment: @user1762447 I've updated with an answer to the second question.